# MySQL: Nested GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I'm receiving an "Invalid use of group function" error when executing this SELECT statement.

```
SELECT kits.id, kits.is_quote,
GROUP_CONCAT(
CONCAT_WS('|||', kits_table.id, kits_table.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT_WS('|', parts_table.id, parts_table.name) 
    SEPARATOR '||'),
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT_WS('|', labor_table.id, labor_table.description) 
    SEPARATOR '||')
)
SEPARATOR '||||') as kits,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', parts.id, parts.name) SEPARATOR '|||') as parts,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', labor.id, labor.description) SEPARATOR '|||') as labor
FROM kits
LEFT  JOIN kits as kits_table ON kits_table.kit_id = kits.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts as parts_table ON parts_table.kit_id = kits_table.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN labor as labor_table ON labor_table.kit_id = kits_table.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts ON parts.kit_id = kits.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN labor ON labor.kit_id = kits.id
WHERE kits.id = '1'
GROUP BY kits.id;
```

I need to be able to SELECT a kit from a database, and within that kit I need the query to return other kits, parts, and labor, with the kits part of that equation also returning parts and labor. If I remove this `GROUP_CONCAT(*) as kits` statement then the query works fine.

Upon request of the tables I'm using these are the tables with the primary info you need:

Table Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `kits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kit_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_quote` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `KIT` (`kit_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `labor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kit_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_quote` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `hours` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `KIT` (`kit_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `parts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kit_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_quote` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_price` varchar(45) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `quantity` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `KIT` (`kit_id`)
)
```

And insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO `kits`
(`id`,
`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`name`,
`description`,
`quantity`)
VALUES
(1,0,0,"Main Kit", "Sample Description",1);

INSERT INTO `kits`
(`id`,
`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`name`,
`description`,
`quantity`)
VALUES
(2,1,0,"Kit within kit", "Sample Description",1);

INSERT INTO `parts`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`name`,
`description`,
`sale_price`,
`quantity`)
VALUES
(1,0,"First Kit Part 1", "Part description","23.5",1);
 INSERT INTO `parts`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`name`,
`description`,
`sale_price`,
`quantity`)
VALUES
(1,0,"First Kit Part 2", "Part description","23.5",1);

INSERT INTO `parts`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`name`,
`description`,
`sale_price`,
`quantity`)
VALUES
(2,0,"Kit within kit part 1", "Sample Part Description","23.5",1);

INSERT INTO `parts`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`name`,
`description`,
`sale_price`,
`quantity`)
VALUES
(2,0,"Kit within kit part 2", "Sample Part Description","23.5",1);

INSERT INTO `labor`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`description`,
`hours`)
VALUES
(1,0,"First Kit labor 1","1.5");

INSERT INTO `labor`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`description`,
`hours`)
VALUES
(1,0,"First Kit labor 2","1.5");

INSERT INTO `labor`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`description`,
`hours`)
VALUES
(2,0,"Kit within kit labor 1","1.5");

INSERT INTO `labor`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`description`,
`hours`)
VALUES
(2,0,"Kit within kit labor 2","1.5");

//Second Kit within kit.

INSERT INTO `kits`
(`id`,
`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`name`,
`description`,
`quantity`)
VALUES
(3,1,0,"Kit within kit 2", "Sample Description",1);

INSERT INTO `parts`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`name`,
`description`,
`sale_price`,
`quantity`)
VALUES
(3,0,"Kit within kit part 1", "Sample Part Description","23.5",1);

INSERT INTO `parts`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`name`,
`description`,
`sale_price`,
`quantity`)
VALUES
(3,0,"Kit within kit part 2", "Sample Part Description","23.5",1);

INSERT INTO `labor`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`description`,
`hours`)
VALUES
(3,0,"Kit within kit labor 1","1.5");

INSERT INTO `labor`
(`kit_id`,
`is_quote`,
`description`,
`hours`)
VALUES
(3,0,"Kit within kit labor 2","1.5");
```

Here is sample output using the above INSERT values. Also note that there CAN be multiple kits within the kits key separated by ||||.

```
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
| id | is_quote |                                                            kits                                                            |      parts       |       labor       |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|  1 |        0 | 2|||Kit within kit|||2|Kit within kit part 1||3|Kit within kit part 2|||2|Kit within kit labor 1||3|Kit within kit labor 2 | 1|First Kit Part | 1|First Kit labor |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Please reduce your question to the core components of the query.

Comment: @juergend Is that better?

Comment: can you make a test for me, I can't do from myself. Can you change the alias of your group_concat in a different way from table name?

Comment: Where does the '1' come from?

Comment: @giuseppestraziota What do you mean by this? Could you give me an example? Which group_concat? I have parts and labor as aliases for the parts and labor group_concats, but the group_concat of kits within the kit can't have aliases because I'm making it a single value. (i.e. kits = "kits_table.id,kits_table.is_quote,partswithinthekit,laborwithinthekit ").

Comment: @Strawberry The 1 I'm assuming you're referring to is WHERE kits.id = '1', that is simply because I copied the code from my query which returns many more values than this. It doesn't really matter, but this is a script which will only be used to fetch a single kit. I could make several requests, but depending on how many kits there are within kits, it could take a really long time to make the number of requests needed.

Comment: I think that the error depends by the first group_concat that have a nested group_concat into. Try to replace the two nested group_concat with a string, and run the query, and if works replace one group_concat and left the second as a string. Anyway I know that the number of group by field have to match with the number of the field of the select, except to the group_concat alias.

Comment: It's just that if the '1' comes from some application code, then I'd completely re-think the whole approach.

Comment: This guy is simulating what I'm trying to achieve. He claims that is is group_concat within group_concat but I'm not understanding how he's generating the e_list on his second SELECT query since there is no group_concat around his SELECT subquery. https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysql-group_concat/

Comment: @Strawberry that is absolutely coming programmatically before the MySQL query is made. How would you make this happen? I didn't want to make multiple queries for each kit because it would take longer. Actually, just thinking about this, I could make the query work with 2 SELECT statements, identical to each other except the second references the first in it's kit_id and since kit_id is not a primary unique key I could get multiples back from that versus the implied LIMIT 1 from the first request. Ideally, however, I'd like it to happen all in one request to optimize time and server resources.

Comment: Another interesting thing that is happening is that I'm getting multiples of the same kit within the GROUP_CONCAT statement when I've removed the nested GROUP_CONCAT, but it doesn't happen for parts or labor from the main kit.

Comment: I would dispense with all the aggregation

Comment: @Strawberry If I split this select statement I would then have to make multiple requests, no? Or is that not what you're referring to?

Comment: @Strawberry Just added that. I didn't think it was necessary in the beginning so I didn't have it. Thanks for looking at this for me! Really do appreciate it.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, forgot the INSERTS. They're in there now.

Comment: @Strawberry I missed removing one of the columns on the labor insert when I copied the parts insert. Sorry! I corrected it.

Comment: Given the `INSERT's` his example, how would the output according to the example?

Comment: @wchiquito I've updated the INSERTs and the SELECT and added an output that should come from using those current statements. I'd recommend truncating those tables and then re-execute the code to get a result like I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```sql
mysql> SELECT
    ->   GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->     CONCAT_WS('|||', 0, 1, 
    ->               GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', 2, 3) SEPARATOR '||')
    ->              )
    ->             ) `test`;
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

mysql> SELECT
    ->   GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->     CONCAT_WS('|||', 0, 1, 
    ->               (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', 2, 3) SEPARATOR '||'))
    ->              )
    ->             ) `test`;
+-------------+
| test        |
+-------------+
| 0|||1|||2|3 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

One possible option:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `parts`, `labor`, `kits`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `kits` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `kit_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `is_quote` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `description` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `quantity` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
    ->   KEY `KIT` (`kit_id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `labor` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `kit_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `is_quote` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `description` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    ->   `hours` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
    ->   KEY `KIT` (`kit_id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `parts` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `kit_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `is_quote` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `description` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `sale_price` varchar(45) DEFAULT '0.00',
    ->   `quantity` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
    ->   KEY `KIT` (`kit_id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `kits`
    -> (`id`,
    -> `kit_id`,
    -> `is_quote`,
    -> `name`,
    -> `description`,
    -> `quantity`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1,0,0,"Main Kit", "Sample Description",1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `kits`
    -> (`id`,
    -> `kit_id`,
    -> `is_quote`,
    -> `name`,
    -> `description`,
    -> `quantity`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (2,1,0,"Kit within kit", "Sample Description",1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `parts`
    -> (`kit_id`,
    -> `is_quote`,
    -> `name`,
    -> `description`,
    -> `sale_price`,
    -> `quantity`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1,0,"First Kit Part", "Part description","23.5",1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `parts`
    -> (`kit_id`,
    -> `is_quote`,
    -> `name`,
    -> `description`,
    -> `sale_price`,
    -> `quantity`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (2,0,"Kit within kit part 1", "Sample Part Description","23.5",1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `parts`
    -> (`kit_id`,
    -> `is_quote`,
    -> `name`,
    -> `description`,
    -> `sale_price`,
    -> `quantity`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (2,0,"Kit within kit part 2", "Sample Part Description","23.5",1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `labor`
    -> (`kit_id`,
    -> `is_quote`,
    -> `description`,
    -> `hours`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1,0,"First Kit labor","1.5");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `labor`
    -> (`kit_id`,
    -> `is_quote`,
    -> `description`,
    -> `hours`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (2,0,"Kit within kit labor 1","1.5");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `labor`
    -> (`kit_id`,
    -> `is_quote`,
    -> `description`,
    -> `hours`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (2,0,"Kit within kit labor 2","1.5");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT kits.id, kits.is_quote,
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->         CONCAT_WS('|||', kits_table.id, kits_table.name,
    ->             (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->                 CONCAT_WS('|', parts.id, parts.name) 
    ->             SEPARATOR '||') FROM parts WHERE parts.kit_id = kits_table.id),
    ->             (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->                 CONCAT_WS('|', labor.id, labor.description) 
    ->             SEPARATOR '||') FROM labor WHERE labor.kit_id = kits_table.id)
    ->         )
    ->     SEPARATOR '||||'
    ->     ) as kits,
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', parts.id, parts.name) SEPARATOR '|||') as parts,
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', labor.id, labor.description) SEPARATOR '|||') as labor
    -> FROM kits
    ->     LEFT JOIN kits as kits_table ON kits_table.kit_id = kits.id
    ->     LEFT OUTER JOIN parts ON parts.kit_id = kits.id
    ->     LEFT OUTER JOIN labor ON labor.kit_id = kits.id
    -> WHERE kits.id = 1
    -> GROUP BY kits.id\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      id: 1
is_quote: 0
    kits: 2|||Kit within kit|||2|Kit within kit part 1||3|Kit within kit part 2|||2|Kit within kit labor 1||3|Kit within kit labor 2
   parts: 1|First Kit Part
   labor: 1|First Kit labor
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```sql
mysql> SELECT kits.id, kits.is_quote,
    ->   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    ->       CONCAT_WS('|||', kits_table.id, kits_table.name,
    ->           (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    ->               CONCAT_WS('|', parts.id, parts.name) 
    ->           SEPARATOR '||') FROM parts WHERE parts.kit_id = kits_table.id),
    ->           (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    ->               CONCAT_WS('|', labor.id, labor.description) 
    ->           SEPARATOR '||') FROM labor WHERE labor.kit_id = kits_table.id)
    ->       )
    ->   SEPARATOR '||||'
    ->   ) as kits,
    ->   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('|', parts.id, parts.name) SEPARATOR '|||') as parts,
    ->   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('|', labor.id, labor.description) SEPARATOR '|||') as labor
    -> FROM kits
    ->   LEFT JOIN kits as kits_table ON kits_table.kit_id = kits.id
    ->   LEFT OUTER JOIN parts ON parts.kit_id = kits.id
    ->   LEFT OUTER JOIN labor ON labor.kit_id = kits.id
    -> WHERE kits.id = 1
    -> GROUP BY kits.id\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      id: 1
is_quote: 0
    kits: 2|||Kit within kit|||3|Kit within kit part 1||4|Kit within kit part 2|||3|Kit within kit labor 1||4|Kit within kit labor 2
   parts: 1|First Kit Part 1|||2|First Kit Part 2
   labor: 1|First Kit labor 1|||2|First Kit labor 2
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: I've attempted to do both a GROUP_CONCAT(SELECT statement) (Returns "Subquery returns more than 1 row error.) and SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(statement) (Returns the same group error received before.)

Comment: This is actually very interesting, because the static values of 2,3 work in my query, but when replaced by values from the database it gives me the group error. So, this does in fact allow a group_concat within a group_concat but I think that having multiple return values prevents the query from working.

Comment: You're a rockstar! Sorry I didn't work into your first answer a bit more, because it was very close to this. Except, upon testing this in a couple use cases which I didn't introduce on here I've found a very strange issue. If there are 2 or more kits, then the parts/labor are duplicated (They show up at least twice. Also, interestingly enough, with no parts or labor in the main kit the ||| pipe delimiter shows up in both the parts and labor keys.)

Comment: If there are more than two parts/labor then the KITS are duplicated. I've updated the insert statements above to have a second kit and more parts/labor for main kit. Truncate the tables and reinsert the values and try again and tell me if you get the same value. Thanks again for working on this! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Since this is kind of a separate issue from the original do you think I should open another question?

Comment: Terrific! I really appreciate all your work on this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the differents between select fields and group by fields.

this is the syntax for the GROUP BY clause in MySQL

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n, 
       aggregate_function (expression)
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
GROUP BY expression1, expression2, ... expression_n;
```

maybe you have to add only kits.is_quote to the group by fields, if the concat_group are seen as aggregate functions

Comment: Could you clarify on this? I am using the GROUP_CONCAT function and that is what I believe the error is referencing. Upon removal of the GROUP BY kits.id the function returns the same error.

Comment: I guess is not possibile to use group_concat nested, I looking for a documentation about this but I've found yet. But my advice about the number of fields in the group by still remain.

Comment: I think it is possible because this guy says he does it, but the code doesn't make a ton of sense to me. https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysql-group_concat/

Comment: In which part of the text that guy uses a group_concat nested in another one? There are nested select but not nested group_concat. When the guy uses the group_concat don't use another one into the brackes of the first one.

Comment: Hmm... You're right. But he is achieving, I think, what it is I'm trying to achieve. How does he make a SELECT statement return multiple items within other multiple items. How is he producing the e_list since that e_list subquery isn't grouped in any way I can see.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a strange naming policy - to have both a column called `id` AND a column called `kit_id` on a table called `kits`. So, I'm not sure if I've got this right. So never mind if it's what you think you're looking for or not; is the following a valid query...

```
SELECT k.id
     , k.name kit_name
     , k.description kit_description
     , k.quantity kit_quantity
     , p.name part_name
     , p.description part_description
     , p.sale_price part_price
     , p.quantity part_quantity
     , l.description labor_description
     , l.hours labor_hours 
  FROM kits k 
  LEFT 
  JOIN parts p 
    ON p.kit_id = k.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN labor l 
    ON l.kit_id = k.id;

+----+----------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+
| id | kit_name       | kit_description    | kit_quantity | part_name           | part_description        | part_price | part_quantity | labor_description    | labor_hours |
+----+----------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+
|  1 | Main Kit       | Sample Description | 1            | First Kit Part      | Part description        | 23.5       | 1             | First Kit labor      | 1.5         |
|  2 | Kit within kit | Sample Description | 1            | Kit within kit part | Sample Part Description | 23.5       | 1             | Kit within kit labor | 1.5         |
+----+----------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

??

Comment: The naming policy isn't strange when you understand what the kit_id is for. The kit_id allows parts, labor, and kits to reference a parent kit. The kit_id on the parent kit is 0, or null, so the kit_id just allows me from having to have 6 tables to having only 3, and just don't use the kit_id when I don't need it.The query is valid, but with all the aliases it would make issues. Additionally, there CAN be 2 or more parts, labor, or kits on each parent kit. So, there could be 5 parts, each with the kit_id of 1, or 5 kits with a kit_id of 1, each with 5 parts with the kit_id of each of the kits.

Comment: Just to reiterate, kit_id is completely separate from id on each kit row. Each kit row has its own unique id, and if it happens to be a sub-kit under another kit then the kid_id would be set to its parent kit's id, but WOULD NOT be equal to its own unique id.

Comment: So, in the kit table 'kit_id' is what we'd normally call 'parent_id'

Comment: Yes, but since parts and labor tables also have kit_id I figured I would keep the same naming conventions.

Comment: OK - I've got a leave it there for now. I'll try to pick it up again tomorrow - if other answers don't nail it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential resolution to the problem, so it might help someone else. This specific query can be done in 2 SELECT statements, but the question is to have it done in 1 SELECT statement, so I won't mark this as an answer.

It's definitely not good if one wants to get more than one main kit, because you'd have to make one request for the list of main kits, and then iterate through a for-loop of those main kits making a query for every kit to get kits within the main kit. Very inefficient.

When the required kit id = 1, then:

```
//Fetch the main kit.
SELECT kits.id, kits.is_quote,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', parts.id, parts.name) SEPARATOR '|||') as parts,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', labor.id, labor.description) SEPARATOR '|||') as labor
FROM kits
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts ON parts.kit_id = kits.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN labor ON labor.kit_id = kits.id
WHERE kits.id = '1'
GROUP BY kits.id;

//Fetch an array of kits where kit_id = 1
SELECT kits.id, kits.is_quote,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', parts.id, parts.name) SEPARATOR '|||') as parts,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', labor.id, labor.description) SEPARATOR '|||') as labor
FROM kits
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts ON parts.kit_id = kits.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN labor ON labor.kit_id = kits.id
WHERE kits.kit_id = '1'
GROUP BY kits.id;
```