# How should my query set up look like?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a website in php for my club with a member list and invoicing. I have setup my database as follows:

Family

```
ID
Family name
Adress
etc.
```

Member, with a link to the family ID

```
ID
Firstname
Family_ID
```

Invoice, with a link to either family database or to the member database

```
ID
Amount
payed
Family_ID
Member_ID
```

Sometimes i want to invoice the family for example the yearly contribution. But sometimes i want to invoice the member itself for the match they are playing.

Now I want to make an overview page that looks a little like below

```
Family name1
        Contribution invoice1
    Member1
        Match invoice 1
    member2
        Match invoice 2
Family name2
        Contribution invoice2
    Member1
        Match invoice 3
    member2
        Match invoice 4
etc....
```

I can off course do a query on all the family's en iterate trough them. And with every row do a query for the family members and a query for the invoices. And then again a query for the invoices per member. But I think there should be a more complicated query to get them all in a big query.

I hope my meaning is clear and you guys can help me with it. If there are some questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit hard without demo data. But let's assume the following approach: First, we build temporary `inv_combined`-table (as a select in the `from`-part), which combines invoices to families and members and assigns a type `contribution` and `member` respectively. This `type` is used later on for sorting. Then, given this combined table, we add family- and member details, respectively. Finally, we sort by `family.name, type, member.firstname`, such that the result lists, for each family, first all contribution invoices, and then all member invoices.
In your php code, you just have to go through the list and watch out for any change in family name, type, and member first name to start new sections.
Hope it helps (and hope it works) :-)

```
select * from
 ( (select "Contribution" as type, if.*
    from invoice if
    where if.family_id is not null
   )
    UNION
   (select "Member" as type, im.*
    from invoice im
    where if.member_id is not null
   )
 ) inv_combined left join family on inv_combined.family_id = family.id
   left join member on inv_combined_member_id = member.id
order by family.name, inv_combined.type, member.firstname
```

Comment: 2 questions back: 1) you hav written 2 times 'if.*/im.*'. What does it do? 2) should 'inv_combined_member_id' be 'inv_combined.member_id' ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to need to do, I believe, is make a subquery within your main query joining those members and invoices with some sort of delimiter. Now, this looks like a really crappy query, and indeed it is complicated, but I have it working at several locations in my application.

```
$query = "SELECT Family.ID, Family.name,
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('|||', Member.ID, Member.Firstname
     COALESCE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
         DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('|', Contribution.ID, Contribution.Amount) 
     SEPARATOR '||') FROM Contribution WHERE Contribution.Member_ID = Member.ID AND Contribution.Family_ID = Family.ID),' '), ' '
 )
SEPARATOR '||||'
) FROM Member WHERE Member.Family_ID = Family.ID) as Members
 FROM Family";


//Execute your query, get back $Families...

foreach($Families as $k1=>$Family) {
    $Family['Members'] = array_filter(explode("||||", trim($Family['Members'])));

    foreach($Family['Members'] as $k2=>$Member) {
        $Member = array_filter(explode("|||", trim($Member)));
        $Member = [
            "ID" => $Member[0],
            "Firstname" => $Member[1],
            "Contributions" => array_filter(explode("||", trim($Member[2])))
        ];

        foreach($Member['Contributions'] as $k3=>$Contribution) {
            $Contribution = array_filter(explode("|", trim($Contribution)));

            $Contribution = [
                "ID" => $Contribution[0],
                "Amount" => $Contribution[1]
            ];
            $Member['Contributions'][$k3] = $Contribution;
        }
        $Family['Members'][$k2] = $Member;
    }
    $Families[$k1] = $Family;
}
```

I ran into some issues with `null` values when I was building it, and I just gave you the bare bones, though I basically rewrote the whole thing for your question. You'll need to modify some of the foreach arrays to make it take care of that extra space at the end, remove any empty strings (`array_filter` should, but just be sure), and deal with `null` values.

Reference for more assistance (where I got the help for this type of query): [MySQL: Nested GROUP_CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767814/mysql-nested-group-concat)

Comment: This really looks complicated. Will have a look at it tomorrow so i have more time to see what all the extra code is that I'm not fmiliar with ;)

Comment: @DutchEcho Was this something you were able to work with? Let me know if you have any questions!